# DASH Profiles that is supported in UWP

Tags: uwp

What are the MPEG-DASH profiles that are supported in UWP? Somehow I am getting `UnsupportedManifestProfile` for the profile `urn:mpeg:dash:profile:isoff-on-demand:2011`.

Answer (score 0):

DASH should be supported, I recommend you use the [Player Framework](https://playerframework.codeplex.com/) also take a look at their samples, they have a DASH sample (needs some setup).